# Is there a way to determine what style the selected text is in

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using this code-snippet:

```
function GetSelectedText()
{
  var selectedText=(
        window.getSelection
        ?
            window.getSelection()
        :
            document.getSelection
            ?
                document.getSelection()
            :
                document.selection.createRange().text
     );
 if(!selectedText || selectedText=="")
 {
    if(document.activeElement.selectionStart)
    {
     selectedText = document.activeElement.value.substring(
          document.activeElement.selectionStart
          . document.activeElement.selectionEnd);
    }
 }
 return selectedText;
}
```

Now, it's obvious that this piece of code will return selected text from a large free text floating. What I am curious about, is how can you determine if selected text is normal, **bold**, *italic*, or underline.

**EDIT:** 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection/focusNode

```
validFormats.indexOf(currentNode.nodeName.toLowerCase()) != -1)
```

Comment: could have all of those within the display if selection cross multiple elements but text strings themselves have no style properties. You would need to look at the dom elements the text came from

Comment: Using this, document.execCommand('bold', false, null); we can set text to Bold. What I am wondering, is that once you set it to bold, or some other text is already bold and you select it, how do you determine it's style from the document.getSelection()